# Generic (almost) self-describing parameters in C++ coupled with a GUI?

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I am faced with the following conundrum: Our software has an abstract base class for algorithm objects. All these objects have a common `execute()` method, e.g.:

```
class Algorithm
{
public:
  // [...]
  virtual void execute() = 0;
  // [...]
};
```

For each algorithm that we want to implement, we simply inherit from the base class and store all loaded algorithm objects in a central location. So far, so good.

The problem now lies in the parameters of an algorithm. We want to be able to describe for each algorithm the parameters that need to be set (by an external class). To this end, we gave each algorithm a `ParameterList` object that contains its parameters. I should clarify that for us, a parameter consists of some kind of type (such as `int`) and a label (such as "Number of iterations).

The problem now begins when we want to connect the `ParameterList` to some kind of GUI. Obviously, our algorithms should have no "knowledge" of the graphical API (Qt, GTK, etc.) that we are using. Yet, on the same side, we want to be able to describe algorithm paramters semantically, for example by specifying that the algorithm requires a *filename*. How this *filename* is then displayed is up to the GUI.

Is there a way to combine this `ParameterList` with some kind of semantic type knowledge?

I realize that this question sounds very vague. However, I am not permitted to post any non-trivial code examples (for NDA reasons). So, has anyone been faced with a similar problem in the past?

To wrap it up: We want our objects to describe the parameters they require to a GUI, without knowing the exact details of the GUI.

Comment: OK, see, *that's* a good question.  And from a new poster, too.  There is hope, after all.

Comment: another virtual method implemented in each algorithm class that gives the list of the required parameters and informations on the type (such filename -> then a text field with a open-file button, integer -> spin button ...) and so on... the GUI asks for the parameters to show for the algo to be executed...why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option here might be to use the visitor pattern.  You can create a base class like this:

```
class Parameter {
public:
    virtual ~Parameter() {} // Polymorphic classes need virtual dtors.

    virtual void accept(ParameterVisitor& v) = 0;
};
```

You could define subclasses like these:

```
class IntParameter: public Parameter {
public:
     virtual void accept(ParameterVisitor& v) {
          v.visit(*this);
     }
};
class FilenameParameter: public Parameter {
public:
     virtual void accept(ParameterVisitor& v) {
          v.visit(*this);
     }
};
```

Note that in each `accept` member function, the type of `*this` is the static type of the class - namely, `IntParameter&` in the first case, and `FilenameParameter&` in the second case.

You can then define a base class `ParameterVisitor` class like this:

```
class ParameterVisitor {
public:
    virtual ~ParameterVisitor() {} // Polymorphic classes need virtual dtors.

    virtual void visit(IntParameter& p) {}
    virtual void visit(FilenameParameter& p) {}
    /* .. etc. .. */
};
```

You can then subclass this visitor to get back the type information:

```
class Gui1ParameterVisitor: public ParameterVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(IntParameter& p) {
        /* ... use GUI1 to create a field for an integer. */
    }
    virtual void visit(FilenameParameter& p) {
        /* ... use GUI1 to create a field for a filename. */
    }
};

class Gui2ParameterVisitor: public ParameterVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(IntParameter& p) {
        /* ... use GUI2 to create a field for an integer. */
    }
    virtual void visit(FilenameParameter& p) {
        /* ... use GUI2 to create a field for a filename. */
    }
};
```

Your `ParameterList` class can then just store a list of `Parameter*`s.  You can then build the GUI by instantiating the appropriate visitor type and then having its `visit` callbacks do all the widget construction.  This ends up being type-safe and recovers the information you need.  It does have the drawback that every time you create a new parameter type, you have to add a new member function `visit` to the `ParameterVisitor` class, but you'd need to do that anyway to do all the GUI building.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is interesting, but isn't it overcomplicated? Why not a very simple metainformation about each parameters, describing the possible type from which the GUI extract the needed interface? Sort of "ffi" for GUI... or similar

Comment: The problem with metainformation is that in order to treat everything generically, you would need to add a bunch of code of the form "if this is an int field, here is how you create the widget, here is how you interpret the widget, etc."  The above approach does this in a type-safe way that doesn't require any casting.

Comment: ah, of course I am missing the "feedback" part that set the value selected in the GUI back to the object. Ok, now I see it :)

Comment: +1 Very nice!  That pattern is a neat way of getting all the parameter types together in one class, so that it's easy to implement all parameter types on all GUIs without having one class for each combination.  Also, it doesn't require the `Parameter` classes to make any assumptions about the types of operations a GUI might need, which may vary wildly between, say, populating a dialog box and interrogating the user over standard input/output.  Those operations would also need GUI-specific arguments with GUI-specific types.  This moves those details into the `ParameterVisitor` classes -- good!

Comment: I like this approach very much, thank you. Am I understanding this correctly: In order for the GUI to actually _set_ the specified parameter, I could store the `Parameter` subclass (for example, `IntParameter`) I get while performing the `visit()` operation?

Comment: @Gnosophilon- Yep, that sounds right. Also, kudos for the interrobang. :-)